# android click notification to open listview's note

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, notifications, listactivity

I have a notification set up inside an **IntentService activity** this way:

```
  // Build the content
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
  builder.setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.Notification_Title));
  builder.setContentText(contextText);
  builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_circle_white_36dp);
  builder.setTicker("ticker title");
  builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
  builder.setAutoCancel(true);

  // Provide the Explicit intent
  Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

  // Add the back stack using TaskBuilder and set the Intent to pending intent
  TaskStackBuilder stackbuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
  stackbuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
  stackbuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(in);
  PendingIntent pi_main = stackbuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  builder.setContentIntent(pi_main);

  // Notification through notification Manager
  Notification notification = builder.build();
  NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  manager.notify(1235, notification);
```

and a **MainActivity** that extends ListActivity with a listview, with the following code to manage a single cell click:

```
OnItemClickListener viewNoteListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {

        // Open ViewNote activity
        Intent viewnote = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewNote.class);

        // Pass the ROW_ID to ViewNote activity
        viewnote.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
        startActivity(viewnote);
    }
};
```

which is called inside onCreate() with:

```
    noteListView = getListView();
    noteListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewNoteListener);
```

Inside the IntentService activity I'm retrieving the cell title (cell is composed by id and title)

**Q.** Is there a way I can open a certain listview cell (knowing it's title) clicking the notification?

EDIT: ViewNote.class is:

```
public class ViewNote extends Activity {

// Declare Variables
private long rowID;
private TextView TitleTv;
private TextView NoteTv;
Button btnEditing;
Button btnDel;
Button btnBack;
private static final String TITLE = "title";
private static final String NOTE = "note";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_note);

    // Locate the TextView in view_note.xml
    TitleTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TitleText);
    NoteTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NoteText);
    btnEditing = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noteEditing);
    btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noteDel);
    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gobackFakeTwo);

    // Retrieve the ROW ID from MainActivity.java
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    rowID = extras.getLong(MainActivity.ROW_ID);

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View emptyView) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View emptyView) {
            DeleteNote();
        }
    });

    btnEditing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View emptyView) {
            Intent addeditnotes = new Intent(ViewNote.this, AddEditNotes.class);

            addeditnotes.putExtra(MainActivity.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addeditnotes.putExtra(TITLE, TitleTv.getText());
            addeditnotes.putExtra(NOTE, NoteTv.getText());
            startActivity(addeditnotes);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Execute LoadNotes() AsyncTask
    new LoadNotes().execute(rowID);
}

// LoadNotes() AsyncTask
private class LoadNotes extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> {
    // Calls DatabaseConnector.java class
    DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewNote.this);

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params) {
        // Pass the Row ID into GetOneNote function in
        // DatabaseConnector.java class
        dbConnector.open();
        return dbConnector.GetOneNote(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        result.moveToFirst();
        // Retrieve the column index for each data item
        int TitleIndex = result.getColumnIndex(TITLE);
        int NoteIndex = result.getColumnIndex(NOTE);

        // Set the Text in TextView
        TitleTv.setText(result.getString(TitleIndex));
        NoteTv.setText(result.getString(NoteIndex));

        result.close();
        dbConnector.close();
    }
}

// Create an options menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Edit Note")
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.EditButtonClickListener)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    menu.add("Delete Notes")
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(this.DeleteButtonClickListener)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// Capture edit menu item click
OnMenuItemClickListener EditButtonClickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        // Pass Row ID and data to AddEditNotes.java
        Intent addeditnotes = new Intent(ViewNote.this, AddEditNotes.class);

        addeditnotes.putExtra(MainActivity.ROW_ID, rowID);
        addeditnotes.putExtra(TITLE, TitleTv.getText());
        addeditnotes.putExtra(NOTE, NoteTv.getText());
        startActivity(addeditnotes);

        return false;

    }
};

// Capture delete menu item click
OnMenuItemClickListener DeleteButtonClickListener = new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        // Calls DeleteNote() Function
        DeleteNote();

        return false;

    }
};

private void DeleteNote() {

    // Display a simple alert dialog to reconfirm the deletion
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewNote.this);
    alert.setTitle("Delete note");
    alert.setMessage("Do you really want to delete this note?");

    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {
            final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(
                    ViewNote.this);

            AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask = new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(Long... params) {
                    // Passes the Row ID to DeleteNote function in
                    // DatabaseConnector.java
                    dbConnector.DeleteNote(params[0]);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                    // Close this activity
                    finish();
                }
            };
            // Execute the deleteTask AsyncTask above
            deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });
        }
    });

    // Do nothing on No button click
    alert.setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
}
```

}

Comment: do you want to open a particular list item in the listview to open when we click on the notification ?

Comment: Yea I'm sorry i reformulated the question cause I forgot to mention about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to launch `MainActivity` on notification click when you have a specific activity to show one item. The only thing required is to know the id of item to be displayed while clicking the notification.

Change

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, ViewNote.class);
in.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3); // While clicking the notification you need to know which item to open
```

Comment: Thanks this is a first step, I reformulated the question though cause I forgot to mention that the cell must be a particular cell of which i know the title

Comment: @m4tt: In general scenario you open the particular item in next activity using its position in the list view. I would suggest to keep another value (like unique id) and use that to open the new activity. This  would help you in both the cases (opening the item with or without the notification).

Comment: I do have ids for the rows, so easiest way for me right now, since theres a complex calculation to retrieve that title value inside IntentService, would be to get cell's id using it's title, is that possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Wouldn't it be better to keep the id in intent service and fetch the title according to that. It always better to keep the unique value in hand. Also depending on the structure of your object it might/might not be possible to get the id. What if there is duplicate title?

Comment: Thats true, I'll need to change the fetch to find id instead as a first step.. then I guess I can find threads about getting title through id on stack. After that I'd only need to place `in.putExtra(ROW_ID);` right? (not sure what arg3 was)

Comment: `arg3` is the position of the cell in the listview. You will have to change the `ViewNote` activity a little. Not much.

Comment: I could retrieve note's id other than title, now the problem is, as you said ViewNote should be modified a bit but how is it possible if inside ViewNote.class it fetches the id from `MainActivity.ROW_ID` storing it inside var `rowID` and using that along the whole activity? (I edited adding ViewNote.class code)

Comment: Solved, I stored fetched id inside var `nID` inside IntentService and wrote `in.putExtra(ROW_ID, nID);` and it works! thanks

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help.